# Shifting text of note on path to the left

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a map of the implications and partial converse implications of three notions of random variable convergence, namely almost certain convergence (indicated by QC), Lp convergence (indicated by $L^p$), and convergence in probability (indicated by P). So far, I have this:

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,2) circle (.8)
(2,2) circle (.8)
(0,0) circle (.8)
(-2,2) node {$\xrightarrow{\text{QC}}$}
(2,2) node {$\xrightarrow{L^p}$}
(0,0) node {$\xrightarrow{\text{P}}$};
\draw[-latex,dashed] (.8,0) to[out=0,in=-90] node[below,sloped] {dominazione} (2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex,dashed] (-.8,0) to[out=-180,in=-90] node[below,sloped] {sottosuccessione} (-2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex,dashed] (-.8,0) to[out=-90,in=30] (-1,-1) to[out=210,in=240] node[below,text width=1cm] {decadi-mento veloce delle $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$} (-3,1) to [out=60,in=180](-2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex] (-2+.8,2) to[out=0,in=90] (0,.8);
\draw[-latex] (2-.8,2) to[out=180,in=90] (0,.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Implications are full arrows and partial converses are dashed ones. The obvious problem is the text `decadimento veloce delle P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)` clashes with the arrow, besides being set to too narrow width. My problem is: how do I tell TikZ to shift it to the left?

PS I also tried the `text along path` option, but it didn't work. Why?

PPS required packages for compiling: `mathtools`, `tikz`, and for the font `mathptmx`. That should give you the same result as the picture is showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `below, sloped,text width=2cm`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,2) circle (.8)
(2,2) circle (.8)
(0,0) circle (.8)
(-2,2) node {$\xrightarrow{\text{QC}}$}
(2,2) node {$\xrightarrow{L^p}$}
(0,0) node {$\xrightarrow{\text{P}}$};
\draw[-latex,dashed] (.8,0) to[out=0,in=-90] node[below,sloped] {dominazione} (2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex,dashed] (-.8,0) to[out=-180,in=-90] node[below,sloped] {sottosuccessione} (-2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex,dashed] (-.8,0) to[out=-90,in=30] (-1,-1) to[out=210,in=240] node[below, sloped,text width=2cm] {decadi-mento veloce delle $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$} (-3,1) to [out=60,in=180](-2,2-.8);
\draw[-latex] (-2+.8,2) to[out=0,in=90] (0,.8);
\draw[-latex] (2-.8,2) to[out=180,in=90] (0,.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `node[below left, text width=2cm] {decadi...`

[image]

Since your text is long, I think text along path may not be the suitable choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify a couple things: I won't use `sloped` because I don't like it. I should have written it in the question that I discarded it in the first place. I did not know of `below left`, which is what makes me accept this answer. The reference to `text along path` was for the other two texts, `dominazione` and `sottosuccessione`.

Comment: @MickG Even for dominazione and sottosuccessione, unless you reduce the font size or increase the node distance, text along path would be terrible. :)